# Parse Time out of A DateTime Field in Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to check the records of an Access Database that has a `SigninTime` field of data type `DATETIME` for any sign in that occurred between 6PM and 8PM.

I've tried:

```
SELECT TestingStatistics.SigninTime
FROM TestingStatistics
WHERE datepart(h,TestingStatistics.SigninTime) >=18;
```

Which asks me to define H

And

```
SELECT TestingStatistics.SigninTime
FROM TestingStatistics
WHERE TestingStatistics.SigninTime >=18;
```

Which just returns everything.

How do you search a DATETIME Field using Time instead of a date?  Furthermore what query should I run?

Answer (score 2):

Try making it a string:

```
datepart("h", TestingStatistics.SigninTime) >= 18;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract JUST the date part of a date/time column with:

DateValue( some date time)

And you can extract JUST the time part of a date/time column with:

TimeValue( some date time)

So, this query would work.

```
Select SignInTime from TestingStatistics
Where TimeValue(SignInTime) between #6 pm# and #8 pm#
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
Where TestingStatistics.SigninTime> Convert(datetime,(Replace(Convert(varchar,GETDATE(),104),'.','-')+ ' 18:00:00.000'),104) and TestingStatistics.SigninTime <= Convert(datetime,(Replace(Convert(varchar,GETDATE(),104),'.','-')+ ' 20:00:00.000'),104))
```

This should show you all the record of today between 18PM-20PM, but You can replace Getdate() for any date that you need.

Hope this help!

Comment: That looks to be t-sql, or syntax related to SQL server - no sql server is noted or involved in this question.